# Normalization / Moving Average

Tags: normalization

I have this daily time series of observed prices: $P_1,P_2,..., P_n$.

I want to works with returns: $ 0  , P_2-P_1,..., P_n - P_{n-1}$.

I have been told to "remove" the first term (P_1-P_0= P_1- ?)  by setting it to 0. It appears that this 0 is very differents from others terms and not a good solution. (I even think it's not a solution at all).

Here are the solution I considered:

- 0 as there is no returns on the first day
- {P_1} to be consistent with the time series
- nothing, just simply removing the problem

what do you think about this problem ?

This remained be about a similar problem I had while doing moving average. There is similar missing terms at the begining of the time series. When doing a p - moving average I usually take the last p value before my date.

- I have the same problem than before: at the beggining of the time series there is not enough data to make a sum with p terms. Is there a trick to adress this problem ?
- Would it change something to take the p values after my date ? the $[(p-1)/2] values before and after my date ? It won't change the general term of my moving average but only the values at the beggining and the end of my time series. does it matter ? How ?

Answer (score 1):

On the moving average question I have previously addressed this using a 'telescoping' approach. If you want an N period MA then for i less than N:

$MA_i = (1 / i) \sum\limits_{j=1}^i p_i $

You then have to decide the trade off between the error in the burn in period and your need for data points and discard as appropriate.